# flex - check image dimensions before upload using filereference

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, filereference, filereferencelist

In my Flex application, I use a `FileReferenceList` that the user can populate with multiple files using `fileList.browse()` before upload.

I check each file's size and use `fileList[i].upload()` to upload to my server, this works fine.

I have a suspicion that this is not possible, but before upload I would like to convert each `FileReference` into an Image in order to check it lies within certain dimension tolerances.

I realise I can do this server side, but ideally I would like the check to appear on both client and server. Can anyone offer any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this post at the Yahoo! Flash Blog](http://www.yswfblog.com/blog/2008/12/22/flash-10-experiments-the-warholizer-loading-and-processing-local-images/). Flash 10 lets you work with images locally. They give a nice example with code of how you can process FileReference objects, specifically image files.